# How is it possible to execute python code during deserialization?

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I was reading about pickling in the context of persisting instances, and ran across this snippet:

> Pickle files can be hacked. If you receive a raw pickle file over the network, don't trust it! It could have malicious code in it, that would run arbitrary python when you try to de-pickle it. [[1]](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle)

My understanding is that pickling turns a data-structure into an array of bytes, and the pickle library also contains methods to take a pickled byte array and rebuild a python instance from it.

I tested some code to see if simply putting code into the class or init method would run it:

```
import pickle

class A:
    print('class')
    def __init__(self):
        print('instance')

a = A()

print('pickling...')
with open('/home/usrname/Desktop/pfile', 'wb') as pfile:
    pickle.dump(a, pfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

print('de-pickling...')
with open('/home/usrname/Desktop/pfile', 'rb') as pfile:
    a2 = pickle.load(pfile)
```

However this only yields

```
class
instance
pickling...
de-pickling...
```

suggesting that the __ init__ method doesn't actually get run when the instance is unpickled. So I'm still confused how you would make code run during that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really thorough writeup here: https://intoli.com/blog/dangerous-pickles/

From what I understand, it has to do with how pickles are interpreted by the Pickle Machine (PM) and run. You can craft a pickle file that will cause it to evaluate using `eval()` the statements provided.